# How to take substring in special position

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

May I ask you how to get a substring after first 2 words and the last word

```
Hello MR Bill Gates
```

I would like to get `Bill` in this case.

Others case:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
```

has to be

```
Server 2008 R2
```

For:

```
Hello amazing world of 2020 year
```

It has to be

```
world of 2020
```

Comment: `' '.join(s.split()[2:-1])` where `s` is your string.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych you answer is correct - please write it as an answer and can "accept" it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, split it into words, select words between second and last, join back into a string:

```
' '.join(s.split()[2:-1])
```

where `s` is your string.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say your string is stored in the variable s
Step 1:
Split your string into words. Words are separated by spaces

```
s.split(' ')
```

Step 2:
Obtain all the words AFTER 2 words and BEFORE the last word

```
s.split(' ')[2:-1]
```

Step 3:
Join these words and return the result

```
' '.join(s.split(' ')[2:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following logic will find the occurrence of space to retrieve its index, and use these indices to slice the input string and finish with strip.

```
input_string = 'Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise'

print(input_string)   

i= [p for p, char in enumerate(input_string) if char == ' ']

result = input_string[i[1]: i[-1]].strip()

print(result)
```

***Updated***: short and sweet:

```
' '.join(input_string.split()[2:-1])
```